# best ways to download files on Android programmatically?

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I'm creating an app in which file downloading is going to happen. I know about asyncTask, Volley and download Manager. Download Manager is not working on redirection, so I'm thinking to use something else.
What are the best ways to download the files pragmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you want to handle these downloads and what is going to be their purposes.

1. Is your app WebView based? If so, then you can make use of a [download listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setDownloadListener(android.webkit.DownloadListener)) which will notify you and handle that action accordingly. E.g:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

2. Are you going to other types of network requests as well? If so, making use of Volley (pretty good [article](https://mobikul.com/downloading-files-using-volley/) exactly for downloading files) makes sense to introduce a library specialized in networking requests otherwise it's just overhead and increases the size of the app.

With no other information I can't relate what use cases you're trying to cover.

Comment: its an app for the general purpose list view, not a webview type. Generally video downloading will be my main focus.